# How to change datetime to just date in a new column in R Programming?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am very new to R but trying my best to learn! Need help adding a column for just the date, parsed from datetime data.

My data looks like this:

```
city | state | datetime
Sand | CA.   | 2017-12-22 14:07:00
```

I would like to add a fourth column with just the date. I thought I could use Lubridate but the function `ymd_hms("datetime")` will not parse the data.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `as.Date` to pull out the date from the date and time.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(datetime))
```

Or if your date time column is just a character, then you need to convert to POSIXct first.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(datetime)))
```

Or in base R:

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$datetime)))
```

**Output**

```
  city state            datetime       date
1 Sand   CA. 2017-12-22 14:07:00 2017-12-22
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(city = "Sand", state = "CA.", datetime = structure(1513980420, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have store the data in dataframe named data then below is code to add a new column of date in your dataframe.

```
data$date = as.Date(data$datetime)
```